# UITextField won't show clear button

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in which I want to display a clear button. The UITextField's cornerRadius has been modified and has no border. I have also added padding to the left and right of the text area. The following code leaves me with no clear button.

```
searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
UIView *padding = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 20)];
searchField.leftView = padding;
searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
searchField.rightView = padding;
searchField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[padding release];
[searchField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
searchField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Does anyone know why I'm unable to get the button to show? 
I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try this

```
[textFieldAddress_ setLeftView:buttonBookmark_];
[textFieldAddress_ setLeftViewMode: UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[textFieldAddress_ setRightView:buttonReloadAndCancel_];
[textFieldAddress_ setRightViewMode: UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing];
textFieldAddress_.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks! That worked for me. Shouldn't Apple's docs point out that having a rightView will override the clear button?

Answer (score 0):

I think just by giving as

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```

you 'll get clear button while editing and setting any corner radius does not affect it.